# How to create a function the encrypts/encrypts JSON data into AES-128-CBC algorithm?

Tags: php, algorithm, encryption, cryptography

Can you help me with my problem? I can't find any good example or tutorial in AES-128-CBC encryption The AES means Advance Encryption Standard and I am new to it. I have a data in JSON format. All I need to do is to create a function for encryption and decryption for my form data. Using the AES-128-CBC algorithm. Any idea how to do it? Or example or any link that can help me with my problem? Thanks in advance. :) By the way I have a reference in this link but I don't know if my data is encrypted in the AES-128-CBC algorithm. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php Here's the code:

```
<?php
    # --- ENCRYPTION ---

    # the key should be random binary, use scrypt, bcrypt or PBKDF2 to
    # convert a string into a key
    # key is specified using hexadecimal
    $key = pack('H*', "bcb04b7e103a0cd8b54763051cef08bc55abe029fdebae5e1d417e2ffb2a00a3");

    # show key size use either 16, 24 or 32 byte keys for AES-128, 192
    # and 256 respectively
    $key_size =  strlen($key);
    echo "Key size: " . $key_size . "\n";

    $plaintext = "This string was AES-256 / CBC / ZeroBytePadding encrypted.";

    # create a random IV to use with CBC encoding
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

    # creates a cipher text compatible with AES (Rijndael block size = 128)
    # to keep the text confidential 
    # only suitable for encoded input that never ends with value 00h
    # (because of default zero padding)
    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key,
                                 $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

    # prepend the IV for it to be available for decryption
    $ciphertext = $iv . $ciphertext;

    # encode the resulting cipher text so it can be represented by a string
    $ciphertext_base64 = base64_encode($ciphertext);

    echo  $ciphertext_base64 . "\n";

    # === WARNING ===

    # Resulting cipher text has no integrity or authenticity added
    # and is not protected against padding oracle attacks.

    # --- DECRYPTION ---

    $ciphertext_dec = base64_decode($ciphertext_base64);

    # retrieves the IV, iv_size should be created using mcrypt_get_iv_size()
    $iv_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, 0, $iv_size);

    # retrieves the cipher text (everything except the $iv_size in the front)
    $ciphertext_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, $iv_size);

    # may remove 00h valued characters from end of plain text
    $plaintext_dec = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key,
                                    $ciphertext_dec, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_dec);

    echo  $plaintext_dec . "\n";
?>
```

The output is

```
Key size: 32
ENJW8mS2KaJoNB5E5CoSAAu0xARgsR1bdzFWpEn+poYw45q+73az5kYi4j+0haevext1dGrcW8Qi59txfCBV8BBj3bzRP3dFCp3CPQSJ8eU=
This string was AES-256 / CBC / ZeroBytePadding encrypted.
```

But is is in AES-256 CBC. How can I create an encryption in AES 128 CBC format?

Comment: Look at the docs for [`mcrypt()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php). That page even has a specific code example for doing an AES 128 encryption using CBC mode.

Comment: Ok I will check that thanks

Comment: https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption - json_encode() then Crypto::encrypt(). On decryption: Crypto::decrypt() then json_decode(). Simple really.

Answer (score 0):

You probably [don't want to use CBC mode in practice](https://robertheaton.com/2013/07/29/padding-oracle-attack/).

Instead, a [well-studied PHP encryption library](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/11/choosing-right-cryptography-library-for-your-php-project-guide) (preferably one that [doesn't use mcrypt](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong)), combined with JSON functions, should solve your problem entirely.

The simplest would be [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption):

```
<?php
use Defuse\Crypto\Crypto;
use Defuse\Crypto\Key;

/**
 * @param array|object $encrypted
 * @param Key $key
 * @return string
 */
function encryptJson($arrayOrObject, Key $key)
{
    $encoded = json_encode($arrayOrObject);
    return Crypto::encrypt($encoded, $key);
}

/**
 * @param string $encrypted
 * @param Key $key
 * @param bool $assoc
 * @return array|object
 */
function decryptJson($encrypted, Key $key, $assoc = false)
{
    $decrypted = Crypto::decrypt($encrypted, $key);
    return json_encode($decrypted, $assoc);
}
```